# Can I use $x \in \{a, b, c\}$ to mean that $a, b$ and $c$ are valid solutions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

When solving an equation, can I use the notation $x \in \{a, b, c\}$ to mean that $x=a$, $x=b$ and $x=c$ are all possible solutions to the equation?

Comment: Well, $x \in \{a,b,c\}$ means that $x=a, x=b$ or $x=c$ but does not mention the word "solution" anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is indeed an acceptable notation.

Example: $x^3-x=0$ exactly for $x\in\{0,1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

By saying that $x \in \{a,b,c\}$, by definition of element of set you are saying that $x=a, x=b, x=c$ . Read more about element of set here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_%28mathematics%29)